# Scaling down spanner nodes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

What are the limitations / considerations in scaling down spanner nodes? Since there is a tight coupling of nodes to data stored - is it fair to say that it is highly scalable but not elastic? The following is a quote from the quizlet case study on GCP website...

"it might be impossible to reduce the number of nodes on your database, even if you previously ran the database with that number of nodes."

The word "might" needs some expanding

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the "might" -- we restrict the reduction of nodes to meet a [2T/node limit](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/quotas#note1) for the instance. You can scale up and down, as long as the down-sizing doesn't cross that threshold.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I understand the limit but what happens if you are under the 2TB limit but the data is split across lots of nodes (you run for temporary performance) and then you reduce?

Comment: I believe, storage and computation is completely separated in spanner design. So decreasing node count should be okay unless you hit limits which are per node, like 2tb storage, session count or others.

Answer (score 0):

A few things we would recommend to scale down effectively is by deleting unused data (databases, tables, global index, rows etc.). This data will be cleaned within ~7 days, allowing you to potentially run with lower node counts.

Comment: Thanks - I appreciate that. I'm trying to get a better handle on the performance dynamics of scaling up and down to meet peak demands.